# ReplayKit and the title of the preview

Tags: ios, replaykit

Another ReplayKit question:

When showing the preview view controller after stopping the recording, ReplayKit seems to use the target name in the title, subtitled by the current date. We would like to change this title since the project name does not fit well there. Is there a possibility to change it? Simply changing the title property won't work. Any fast hack / workaround would be really helpful until adding this possibility in one of the later versions of ReplayKit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again I found the answer myself. What's used is not exactly the target name, but "Product Name" from Build Settings. A simple change of that did it.

Comment: Don't work for me :'( Is there a chance that it's overriden somewhere ?

Comment: My bad, it did work! But what i'm trying to change is the produced filename (and better yet, the social pre-filled message)

Comment: Note that changing the Product Name in Build Settings may have some bad side effect, such as changing your app swift to objc bridge header file (autogenerated at build, but manually imported in your code)